# Fisher test to aggregate p-values in a simulation (from Wilcoxon rank-sum tests )- interpret correctly null-hypothesis

Tags: probability-theory, hypothesis-testing, simulation, fisher-information

I got contradictory results between p-values in single trials, obtained with Wilcoxon test, and Fisher's p-value, obtained from a simulation over 1000 trials.

I am confused about correctly interpreting the null-hypothesis and p_values obtained from a simulation. Can you please explain and help in interpreting results, and correct wrong ideas ? I don't feel to have yet solid background in statistics, grateful if you can help in grasping key concepts better and design an experiment that actually test what I meant to test.

Consider this experiment:

I have a list of sequences associated to two different contexts:

- context_1 - [[33, 33], [33], [23, 36, 35], ...]
- context_2 - [[356, 122, 45], ... ]

Those numbers represent how common tokens are in a sequence, observed for a given context (you may think that the sequence is like a sentence that encode the frequencies of observed words, e.g.  if "apple" is frequent 33 times in a vocabulary, then 33, 33 encode apple, apple ". I am working with animal sounds).

Null hypothesis :

- sequences follows a similar distribution

Alternate:

- sequences do not follow a similar distribution

I am using Wilcoxon rank-sum test.
As control experiment, I compare the samples belonging to the same context (say, context_1), and run a simulation for *n* times (say, *n=1000*).

- Example: `rank_sum([33, 33], [33]), rank_sum([33], [23, 36, 35]) , ...`
- collect the 1000 p_values

I see that majority of p-values (97%) are above 0.05, that is, I interpret that I cannot reject the null hypothesis and the **single** trials follows the same distribution.

Now, I want to aggregate those p_values of the simulation.
I use Fishers' method.

And I found that p_value of the "aggregated" 1000 p_values is: 0.

That is, I should reject the null-hyptothesis and the samples do not come from the same ditribution.

But in fact they are.

That is confounding:

- why I get contradictory results between the majority of single trials using Wilcoxon and the final p-value using Fisher ?
- Is the null hypothesis I am testing with Fisher equivalent to the one I am testing with Wilcoxon, or is it another thing?

FYI:
I am computing Fisher p value like this:

```
n = 1000 # simulation
p_values = [ rank_sum([33, 33], [33]), rank_sum([33], [23, 36, 35]) , ... ] #1000 p-values
chi2_statistic = -2 * np.sum(np.log(p_values))
degrees_of_freedom = 2 * n
fisher_p_value = 1 - chi2.cdf(chi2_statistic, degrees_of_freedom)
```

Ref:

- https://data.library.virginia.edu/the-wilcoxon-rank-sum-test/
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_method

---

## Edited

If I run the simulation 1000 times against the same sequences, I have a list of 1000 p-values with all 1.0 (...they likely come from the same distribution, and if fact they are since I am comparing the same sequence over and over)

But I apply Fisher's on those p-value lists, I got 0.

- Why is that ?
- I am confused in interpreting the p-value of Fisher.